# after disabling dpms, how to keep dpms disabled after resume from suspend?

Tags: suspend, power-management

Ubuntu 12.10 quantal: On login, I run "xset -dpms s 0 0 s off". This works great until I suspend and resume. For some reason, dpms is re-enabled after resume. Is there an easy way to completely disable DPMS without recompiling X?

Answer (score 0):

Power-manager and screensaver fiddle with the settings while they are running. – Make sure you have them under control.